# Not Inherit from Base Class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let me get this straight. This is an interview question which I am not able to solve till now.Consider two classes

```
class A
{
     public : virtual int f() { };
              int a;
 }

class B : public A
{

     public : virtual int g() { };
              int b;
}
```

When asked the size of A and B I said correctly 8 and 12. The next question was how to define the class B so that it neglects the first 8 bytes derived from A. He said this is possible. I still can't understand how it is possible. Can anybody explain how this can be done?

**Edit :** The real question is not finding the size of classes but the followup.

Comment: What a useless interview question. Calculating sizes of classes? Really?

Comment: @DanielDaranas While I agree it's an odd question, I think it was masked way of determining if the interviewee understands how/what vtables are and/or normal sizes for scalar types.

Comment: Just don't derive `B` from `A`.

Comment: "The next question was how to define the class B so that it neglects the first 8 bytes derived from A."  Maybe there is something I am missing, but to do this, all you have to do is make B not derived from A, i.e. remove ": public A".

Comment: Also, "neglect the first 8 bytes derived from A"? Does this even have any sense?

Comment: @DanielDaranas - not calculating, guessing. It depends on the compiler.

Comment: @DanielDaranas The real question was not really the sizeof the classes. He knew that I know the answer for that question.That question was merely a way to get to the second question.Cheers!

Comment: @DanielDaranas: *"Does this even have any sense"* It does, if interviewer foolishly believes that he's on 32bit platform and vtable is guaranteed to use only single pointer.

Comment: @user1429322: I suggest to post the answer once you're done with the interview. For me it sounds like interviewer is trying to be a smart*** and is essentially wasting time.

Comment: Show me someone who can't make an educated (and almost certainly correct) guess about the size of those classes, given basic information about the platform, and I'll show you an inexperienced C++ programmer.

Comment: @SigTerm I will post it once I get to know the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what answer the questioner was expecting, but here's some possible solutions:

**Make 'A' a pointer:**

```
//Only takes 4 or 8 bytes (32 bit vs 64 bit code) for 'A', regardless of 'A's actual size, but must point to an 'A' located elsewhere in memory with the full size.
class B
{
   A *a; //Only 4 bytes.
   int b;
};
```

**Make 'A' static:**

```
//Doesn't assume any of 'A's size, but all instances of 'B' shares a single instance of 'A'.
class B
{
    static A a;

    int b;
};
```

**Pass 'A' into the functions of 'B':**

```
//Pass in the reference to 'a' when needed, so multiple 'B's can share the same 'a' explicitly when desired.
class B
{
    void q(A &a) { this->b + a.a; return a.g(); }
};
```

**Make 'A' and 'B' not have virtual tables** (probably the interviewer's point)

```
//By not having virtual functions, you save the (really small) cost of 4 bytes (8 bytes on 64 bit machines)
class A
{
public:
     int f() { }; //Not virtual
     int a;
}

class B : public A
{
public:
     int g() { }; //Not virtual
     int b;
}
```

It still costs you the size of A::a, and, unless you re-use 'a' in B instead of having B::b, you can't avoid those 4 bytes. And re-using one variable to mean something else entirely is a possible sign of really bad programming habits.

**Unionize A'a and B's variables and put the functions in a single class**

```
class AB //Only 4 bytes total
{
   public:
   union
   {
       int a;
       int b;
   };

   void f();
   void g();
};
```

The bad idea about this is, you'll have to keep track of whether you should access 'a' or 'b', because both of them occupy the same 4 bytes of memory, and they can't both be using it at the same time.

Another bad thing about this is that it is a sign that the class has too much responsibility. Is it an A or a B? If it's both, the all important question should be, "Why is it both?". It should have a [single-responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), not be a [monolith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179396/what-does-monolithic-mean) of mixed purposes.

**Make 'A' a template, and inherit from `A<B>`:**

```
template<typename TypeB>
class A
{
    int a;
};

//Saves the cost of the virtual table... not that that really matters.
class B : public A<B>
{
    int b;
};
```

This last one is called the '[curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)' (CRTP)
The idea is that the inherited '`A<B>`' can call access variables and functions from 'B' (if you pass B's 'this' pointer into A's constructor), and 'B' can access variables and functions directly from '`A<B>`'.

You're inheriting from a compile-time generated version of the template 'A', that is generated for 'B'.

Comment: It is the first time I see that form of your last example. Would you mind detailing a little what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: Sure, it's called the 'Curiously recurring template pattern' - editted the answer.

Comment: I mentioned that in my post, "*The idea is that the inherited 'A<B>' can call access variables and functions from 'B' (if you pass B's 'this' pointer into A's constructor)*", but I wasn't too clear about it.

Comment: @Jamin - Oops - sorry.

Comment: Well, you're right about it not being CRTP *unless* A can access B directly - I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the interviewer's question, but another possible way manipulating the inheritance of A and B is to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//This concept was taken from a Going Native 2013 talk called "C++ Seasoning" given by Sean Parent
//
//Located here: (about 101 minutes into it)
//http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning

//Polymorphism without inheritance.
//Permits polymorphism without using pointers or references,
//and allows them to be copied around easier (each instance is actually its own object) rather
//than accidentally shallow-copying when you wanted deep-copies.
//
//Every time Object::Print() is called, it calls
// Object::PrintableConcept::Print(), which virtually calls
// Object::PrintableModel<TYPE>::Print(), which calls your
// "derived" class that implements the Print() function, regardless
// of what that class inherits (if anything).
class Object //Class without inheritance or virtual.
{
    public:
    template<typename Type>
    Object(Type instance) : self(std::make_shared<PrintableModel<Type>>(std::move(instance)))
    { }

    //Calls the "inherited" function.
    void Print() const
    {
        self->Print();
    }

    private:
    struct PrintableConcept //The concept we want to polymorphably access.
    {
        virtual ~PrintableConcept() = default;
        virtual void Print() const = 0;
    };

    //The class that concretely models the concept,
    //and does the actual inheritting.
    template<typename Type>
    struct PrintableModel : public PrintableConcept
    {
        PrintableModel(Type instance) : data(std::move(instance)) { }

        //Every time 
        void Print() const override
        {
            this->data.Print();
        }

        Type data;
    };

    //This should be a unique_ptr, but you also need to make sure
    //you implement proper copy operators in this class and move support.
    std::shared_ptr<PrintableConcept> self;
};

class Whatever
{
    public:
    void Print() const { std::cout << "Whatever\n" << std::endl; }
};

class SomethingElse
{
    public:
    void Print() const { std::cout << "SomethingElse\n" << std::endl; }
};

class WidgetThing
{
    public:
    void Print() const { std::cout << "WidgetThing\n" << std::endl; }
};

typedef std::vector<Object> Document;

int main()
{
    Document document;
    document.emplace_back(Whatever());
    document.emplace_back(SomethingElse());
    document.emplace_back(WidgetThing());

    for(const auto &object : document)
    {
        object.Print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<<< [Run the code](http://ideone.com/R5xEs4) >>>

None of the classes actually inherit from 'Object' (or from anything else), but can be used interchangeably with each other in, say, a vector, because they all implement a common interface (`PrintableConcept`) that Object accesses templatedly, but Object itself isn't a template and so doesn't become `Object<something>` and `Object<something-else>` which would've been separate types.